# How can I make an interface in TypeScript that only accepts keys with identical value types between two objects?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

How can I make an interface in TypeScript that only accepts keys with identical value types between two objects?
I'm having trouble creating interface..

```
interface A {
    aString: string;
    aNumber: number;
}

interface B {
    bString: string;
    bNumber: number;
}

interface C {
    aKey: keyof A;
    bKey: keyof B;
    // but only wants to accept keyof B when only typeof current A[keyof A] === typeof B[keyof B]
}
```

I'm expecting the result

```
const c1: C = { // success typeof A.aString === typeof B.bString
    aKey: 'aString',
    bKey: 'bString', 
}

const c2: C = { // fail typeof A.aString !== typeof B.bNumber
    aKey: 'aString',
    bKey: 'bNumber',
}
```

Is there anyway to do this?..
ChatGPT suggests to filter the keyof B that only contained in values of A but it only makes every keyof B possible.

Comment: You can't do this with an *interface*, but you can compute a union type that behaves this way, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w1Qalw). Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz You're not missing anything. that's the solution I was looking for. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no specific [`interface`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces) type that works this way, since you can't make one property depend on another.  You could make a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) interface, but then you'd need to specify or infer the generic type argument all over the place and that could be annoying.  Since you have a finite number of properties to worry about, you can represent `C` as a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) instead of an interface.  It would look like

```
type C = {
    aKey: "aString";
    bKey: "bString";
} | {
    aKey: "aNumber";
    bKey: "bNumber";
}
```

so that only the two valid pairings of `aKey` and `bKey` work:

```
const c1: C = {
  aKey: 'aString',
  bKey: 'bString',
} // okay

const c2: C = {
  aKey: 'aString',
  bKey: 'bNumber',
} // error
```

---

The above definition for `C` was written out manually, but you can make the compiler *compute* it by iterating over the keys of (say) `A`, and finding each property key of `B` whose property matches.  This would need some sort of `KeysMatching<T, V>` type which gives you the keys of `T` whose values are compatible with `V`.  There is no built-in operator for this (see [microsoft/TypeScript#48992](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48992) for the feature request), but you can write your own in various ways; here's one way:

```
type KeysMatching<T, V> = 
  keyof { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends V ? K : never]: 0 };
```

That uses [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to filter keys by property type.  Then `C` can be written as

```
type C = { 
  [K in keyof A]: { aKey: K, bKey: KeysMatching<B, A[K]> } 
}[keyof A];
```

That's a so-called *distributive object type* where I make a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) that computes the desired type for each key of `A`, and then immediately [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) it to get the desired union.

You can verify that the above evaluates to the same definition for `C` as the manual one.  And if you add/change properties to `A` and `B`, the definition of `C` will change accordingly.  There's a wrinkle that if you have multiple keys of `A` with the same property type you might get a less optimized union type as a result; imagine `{aKey: "x", bKey: "z"} | {aKey: "y", bKey: "z"}` instead of `{aKey: "x" | "y", bKey: "z"}`, but it will still be correct.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAguE8AcFMAIGlrgM4FkCGoDGALAlgHYDmAPACoA0sAagHywC8sA1kgPYBmsA3rANrxYhFuy5lY6ZLDICAurGgAPUNAIATKdVgB+BLABcsAtABu0AE6zDABlgBfANwhCK8x3RY4AQR7BYEgGVQc0IiQ2Rg0Kd-dAA5AFcAWwAjC0MCJNTzJztnAld3T1gAIV9-ZKCQ4nDI4mjYZISUtKNMixzgCBhYAGFGHn5BYVZwTlgvKwH0RHBDeCpkmbmkNExcUJJiqi85ejt7PhGxiacAegAqWC64PqZuP38JJdgAInRK0Jf68ueXitqiF9gPsAD5lR7TJCGN5NLJAx4NX6NNrmIH7c6nEBYNgECKwLAARkMt3BkNmsAA5O8ARSKA9FlDKf8qkRacDYKdTrA2Mx0OAsTi8VgAEzE-r3GLPKkfYhsn6MinI5rmNn7TkKczmNjmEBAA)